# Filter a list of sites by multiple tags

Tags: javascript, html, filter, tags

I have this page to search sites by tags but I have 3 problems:

1) If another site is added into the list (Site 4), why does it no longer work?

2) Where should the sites links be inserted?

3) Is there any way to hide tags from displaying in the page?

```js
var data = 
[
   {
     "name": "Site 1",
      "tags": ["1", "2", "3"]
    },
   {
     "name": "Site 2",
      "tags": ["1", "2"]
    },
   {
     "name": "Site 3",
      "tags": ["2", "3"]
    }
]

window.search = function() {

 var toSearch = document.getElementById("myInput").value.toUpperCase();
  var filterFunction = function(element) {
   return false;
  }
  if (toSearch.length) {
   var tagsProvided = toSearch.split(/[ ,\t]/);
    filterFunction = function(element) {
     var keep = true;
      for (var i = 0; i < tagsProvided.length; ++i) {
         var tagProvided = tagsProvided[i];
         if (tagProvided.length < 1) continue;
         
         var currentTagFound = false;
         for (var j = 0; j < element.tags.length; ++j) {
           currentTagFound |= (tagProvided.toUpperCase() == element.tags[j].toUpperCase());
         }
         keep &= currentTagFound;
      }
      return ! keep;
    }
  }
  
  ul = document.getElementById("myUL");
  
  while (ul.lastChild) {
    ul.removeChild(ul.lastChild);
  }
  
  for (var i = 0; i < data.length; ++i) {
    var element = data[i];
   if (filterFunction(element)) continue;
    
    var li = document.createElement("li");
    
    var a = document.createElement("a");
    a.appendChild(document.createTextNode(element.name + " (" + element.tags.join(", ") + ")"));
    a.setAttribute("href", "#");
    
    li.appendChild(a);
    ul.appendChild(li);
  }  
}

search();
```

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

#myInput {
  background-image: url('/css/searchicon.png');
  background-position: 10px 12px;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  width: 100%;
  font-size: 16px;
  padding: 12px 20px 12px 40px;
  border: 1px solid #ddd;
  margin-bottom: 12px;
}

#myUL {
  list-style-type: none;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

#myUL li a {
  border: 1px solid #ddd;
  margin-top: -1px; /* Prevent double borders */
  background-color: #f6f6f6;
  padding: 12px;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 18px;
  color: black;
  display: block
}

#myUL li a:hover:not(.header) {
  background-color: #eee;
}
```

```html
<body>
<h2>My WebSites</h2>

<input type="text" id="myInput" onkeyup="search()" placeholder="Search for tags.." title="Type in a tag">

<ul id="myUL">
</ul>
```

Comment: For the first question, it works for a 4, 5, 6 site. You did some kind of error inserting the site in your Json.

Comment: For the second question in your <a> element in href

Comment: For the third, do not display the tags in the <a> element

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here you have what you want.

```js
var data = 
[
   {
     "name": "Site1",
      "link":"stackoverflow.com/questions/44601766/filter-a-list-of-sites-by-multiple-tags",
      "tags": ["1", "2", "3"]
    },
   {
      "name": "Site2",
      "link": "www.w3schools.com",
      "tags": ["1", "2"]
    },
   {
     "name": "Site 3",
      "tags": ["2", "3"]
    },
    {
     "name": "Site 4",
      "tags": ["4", "3"]
    },
     {
     "name": "Site 5",
      "tags": ["4", "2", "5"]
    }
]

window.search = function() {

 var toSearch = document.getElementById("myInput").value.toUpperCase();
  var filterFunction = function(element) {
   return false;
  }
  if (toSearch.length) {
   var tagsProvided = toSearch.split(/[ ,\t]/);
    filterFunction = function(element) {
     var keep = true;
      for (var i = 0; i < tagsProvided.length; ++i) {
         var tagProvided = tagsProvided[i];
         if (tagProvided.length < 1) continue;
         
         var currentTagFound = false;
         for (var j = 0; j < element.tags.length; ++j) {
           currentTagFound |= (tagProvided.toUpperCase() == element.tags[j].toUpperCase());
         }
         keep &= currentTagFound;
      }
      return ! keep;
    }
  }
  
  ul = document.getElementById("myUL");
  
  while (ul.lastChild) {
    ul.removeChild(ul.lastChild);
  }
  var newhrefid;
  for (var i = 0; i < data.length; ++i) {
    var element = data[i];
   if (filterFunction(element)) continue;
    
    var li = document.createElement("li");
    
   var a = document.createElement("a");
  a.appendChild(document.createTextNode(element.name));
    a.setAttribute("href", "http://"+element.link);
   li.appendChild(a);
   ul.appendChild(li);
  }  
}

search();
```

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

#myInput {
  background-image: url('/css/searchicon.png');
  background-position: 10px 12px;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  width: 100%;
  font-size: 16px;
  padding: 12px 20px 12px 40px;
  border: 1px solid #ddd;
  margin-bottom: 12px;
}

#myUL {
  list-style-type: none;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

#myUL li a {
  border: 1px solid #ddd;
  margin-top: -1px; /* Prevent double borders */
  background-color: #f6f6f6;
  padding: 12px;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 18px;
  color: black;
  display: block
}

#myUL li a:hover:not(.header) {
  background-color: #eee;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<body>
<h2>My WebSites</h2>

<input type="text" id="myInput" onkeyup="search()" placeholder="Search for tags.." title="Type in a tag">

<ul id="myUL">
</ul>
```

Any doubt, just ask for my help.

Comment: Thank you very much, Jose! If possible, I would like to introduce myself a custom link for each option(site). Ex. Site 1 to have "link1", Site 2 to have "link2" etc. Link is different from the name of the page.

Comment: If I understand you, you need to have a different name presentation than the link name. This is easy, create a new entry in your Json, example "link". And in your <a> element in href, select the link.

Comment: Thank you, Jose Marques, you are the best!